# Field extension definition: short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am confused about the definition of a field extension. How does this relate to the notion of an extension of modules?

If $A$ is a commutative ring and $M$, $N$, and $P$, are $A$-modules, we say that $M$ is an extension of $N$ by $P$ if there is a short exact sequence
$$0\to N \to P \to M\to 0$$.

If $F$ is a field, we say $E$ is a field extension of $F$ if $E$ is a subfield of $F$. This is equivalent to saying that there is an injective ring homomorphism $E\to F$ where $E$ and $F$ are feilds.

Is there a way to phrase a field extension in terms of an exact sequence?
$$0\to E\to K\to F\to 0$$

Comment: Yes there is but not the way you wrote. Instead, $$0 \to E \to F$$

Comment: @LeeMosher so field extensions a different notion of extension than the notion of extension for modules/groups? Is there a more general concept that field extensions fit into? I would have have expected field extensions to be of the form $0\to E\to E[x_1,\ldots, x_n]\to F\to 0$

Comment: *Extension* is one of those plain, vanilla, English words that gets reused for different purposes in different aspects of mathematics. It's sometimes tempting to guess at some kind of unity amongst different uses. But sometimes there is no such unity, and trying to impose one is artificial and unuseful.

Comment: One thing that can be said is that for a short exact sequence of $A$-modules as you have written it, one sometimes says that *$P$ is an extension of $N$* **by $M$**; the point here is that the quotient, namely $P/N \approx M$, often plays an important role. But for a general field extension $0 \mapsto E \mapsto F$, I don't think that any kind of quotient $F/E$ plays much of a role in the theory, although perhaps someone who knows the subject better could correct me on that.

Comment: A field $K$ (viewed as a ring) only admits trivial ideals $\{0\}$ and $K$, and the quotient ring is (isomorphic to) $K$ and $\{0\}$ respectively. That is you can not expect a field to have non-trivial "quotient structure".